# Svelte : build component into AMD module in rollup

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, svelte-3, svelte-component

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let name; // widget name
    let childComponent;

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    onMount(() => {
        switch(name) {
            case 'Widget1':
                import('./Widget1.svelte')
                    .then(res => childComponent = res.default)
                    .catch(err=> { throw "Cannot load component `" + name+ '` ' +  err.message; });
                break;

            case 'Widget2':
                import('./Widget2.svelte')
                    .then(res => childComponent = res.default)
                    .catch(err=> { throw "Cannot load component `" + name + '` ' +  err.message; });
                break;

            // more cases ...

            default:
                throw "Unknown component `" + name + '` ';
        }
            
    });

</script>

<svelte:component this={childComponent}>
        
</svelte:component>
```

The above code works well except that the long `case`s.

My Svelte project is packed into AMD by rollup .
E.g. `Widget1.svelte` is built into `Widget1-69d8780f.js` which is load lazily.

Can rollup build my widgets into individual AMD module without listing them in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but looking at your code, I don't see the need for a `switch` statement? You could simply do:

```js
..
    onMount(() => {
        import(path)
            .then(res => childComponent = res.default)
            .catch(err=> { throw "Cannot load component `" + path + '` ' +  err.message; });
    });
..
```

The only thing missing is the default statement, but I'm assuming that if you attempt to load an non-existing path, the import will throw?

Unless you're explicitly listing all components in order for Rollup to pick them up, and in this case I don't see a way around it.

#### Update: possible Rollup configuration

I have played around with Rollup configuration options with your stated goal in mind:

- iterate through a collection of Svelte components (for the sake of simplicity, I have assumed they were all in a single directory, but this can be expanded upon)
- for each component, output a corresponding AMD module *of the same name* without extra chunk information (this is actually the default behavior when you have an array of entry points)

```js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'

import { readdirSync } from 'fs'

export default {
  input: readdirSync('src/widgets').map((s) => `src/widgets/${s}`),
  output: {
    dir: 'build',
    format: 'amd',
  },
  plugins: [svelte(), resolve(), commonjs()],
}
```

The `svelte` plugin is obviously mandatory here, and I've included the `resolve` and `commonjs` for eventual external dependencies (I do believe the `resolve` plugin is also required to add svelte as a dependency).

Upon building an example project, the build directory gets filled with the corresponding output modules (one per component), plus an `index-<chunk>.js` module that - I believe - holds the Svelte dependency (i.e. all the Svelte helper methods used in the component modules).

I am however unable to properly test the output (my knowledge of AMD is very limited and I've never used requirejs). [Here is a gist of the components + the rollup config above](https://gist.github.com/jaxxeh/88b401b3fe97722f2aba6d4bde5ae6bb).

Comment: This is the problem here,  the path `./Widget1.svelte` actually only exists during development.  When the project is published,  it is built into an AMD js file. 1. How can I instruct rollup to build the widgets into AMD modules without listing them?  2. How to know the output filename(currently it is `Widget1_<random>.js`) so that I can use requirejs to load?

Comment: So, just to be sure I understand your objective, you want to build a set of `Widget<xyz>.svelte` components into their corresponding `Widget<xyz>.js` AMD modules, and not have to list all components inside the source itself, correct?

Comment: yes,  exactly!    I am still trying different config in rollup to make this happen

Comment: @Mr.WangfromNextDoor Came up with a possible rollup config, builds w/o errors, but I'm unable to actually test the built modules. See updated answer, hopefully it'll be useful to you.